# Optimized way of joining a table to itself and return only matching values (also delete this rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have this map table:

```
CREATE TABLE `items_map` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `context` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `md5_hash` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `idx_map` (`context`, `id`),
    INDEX `idx_hash` (`md5_hash`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `items_map` (`id`, `context`, `md5_hash`) VALUES
    (1, 'coupons', 'f46902f68e1f0f56bd97d2c209874c93'),
    (3, 'countries', 'f46902f68e1f0f56bd97d2c209874c93'),
    (1, 'coupons', 'ed63e3a460c4fdef7223dd796dbe6848'),
    (15, 'regions', 'ed63e3a460c4fdef7223dd796dbe6848'),
    (1, 'coupons', '06786a4bc64c718118c1510d06e334a8'),
    (16, 'regions', '06786a4bc64c718118c1510d06e334a8'),
    (1, 'coupons', '2e7536e21183723b99b77c48503e3122'),
    (17, 'regions', '2e7536e21183723b99b77c48503e3122'),
    (2, 'coupons', 'f4df7e36910612dfb39463c874fc27c4'),
    (46, 'countries', 'f4df7e36910612dfb39463c874fc27c4'),
    (2, 'coupons', 'd40faa1e775d0df3864456f10f2995a7'),
    (579, 'regions', 'd40faa1e775d0df3864456f10f2995a7'),
    (2, 'coupons', '3cc0b00ea1c092a8dcd95d225519e8a4'),
    (580, 'regions', '3cc0b00ea1c092a8dcd95d225519e8a4');
```

I want to return ONLY regions and countries based in the selected coupon id.

Tested select query I can use:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT m.context AS code, m.id AS value
FROM items_map AS m
INNER JOIN items_map AS m2 ON m2.context = 'coupons' AND m2.id = 1 AND m.md5_hash = m2.md5_hash
WHERE m.context != 'coupons';

"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "filtered"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "m2"    "ref"   "idx_map,idx_hash"  "idx_map"   "157"   "const,const"   "7" "100,00"    "Using where"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "m" "ref"   "idx_map,idx_hash"  "idx_hash"  "96"    "test.m2.md5_hash"  "1" "100,00"    "Using where"
```

---

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT m2.context AS code, m2.id AS value
FROM items_map AS m
INNER JOIN items_map AS m2 ON m.md5_hash = m2.md5_hash AND m2.context != 'coupons'
WHERE m.context = 'coupons' AND m.id = 1;

"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "filtered"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "m" "ref"   "idx_map,idx_hash"  "idx_map"   "157"   "const,const"   "7" "100,00"    "Using where"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "m2"    "ref"   "idx_map,idx_hash"  "idx_hash"  "96"    "test.m.md5_hash"   "1" "100,00"    "Using where"
```

Both query return correct values:

```
"code"  "value"
"countries" "3"
"regions"   "15"
"regions"   "16"
"regions"   "17"
```

Delete query I´m using:

```
DELETE 
FROM items_map
WHERE md5_hash IN (SELECT m3.md5_hash FROM (
SELECT m2.md5_hash
FROM items_map AS m
INNER JOIN items_map AS m2 ON m2.context = 'coupons' AND m2.id = 1 AND m.md5_hash = m2.md5_hash
WHERE m.context != 'coupons') AS m3);
```

Questions / Request:

1- There is a better way to run this query?

2- Please show me a query for delete this map records based in the "id" and "context". For example; if I want to delete all map records where id = 1 and context = coupons and also delete the mapped rows containing the same md5_hash value.

Important:
Please give options that can be used in multiple databases engines.

Comment: How large are these tables? Are there any assumptions you can make about the data? If you GROUP BY(MD5_HASH) will all groups having count(*) == 2 contain a coupon and then a region or country? Is the coupon ID always less than the region or country ID?

Comment: @JustinDanielson This table contain 10k+ of rows and map items from diferent "context" coupons <-> countries, coupons <-> regions, coupon <-> products, currencies <-> countries etc. The items_map id is an auto increment primary key from other tables (context).

Answer (score 0):

The two queries will perform simikarly. Your biggest optimization is *not* to select, but ratger to use mysql's multi-table delete:

```
DELETE m2
FROM items_map m
JOIN items_map m2 ON m.md5_hash = m2.md5_hash
WHERE m.context = 'coupons'
AND m.id = 1
```

Note that you should deleted from the joined table m2, because the joined table will include matching md5 rows and the rows from m, which is what you want.

---

For a query that will work in any database:

```
DELETE FROM items_map
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT m2.id
    FROM items_map m
    JOIN items_map m2 ON m.md5_hash = m2.md5_hash
    WHERE m.context = 'coupons'
    AND m.id = 1)
```

Comment: I can´t use JOIN in DELETE because there is no JOIN available for the DELETE statement in for example, PostgreSQL. I'm currently using that query, but that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: @MichaelEpstein I added a universal version that should work on any database. I used the mysql-only syntax because the question was tagged "mysql"

Comment: ♦ I added my actual delete query. As you can see, I can't delete by id because a different content can contain the same id, for example, the coupon id 5 can contain the same country.

Comment: Yes - I assumed that a column called "id" would be unique. I can not recall ever encountering a situation where is was not. My advice is to add a primary key column and populate it with unique values. Your life will be easier. It will be easier still if you rename "id" to something meaningful and call your primary key column "id". It's an industry standard you should follow.